# A counting estimate of the number of representations in Goldbach problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

This is going to be a question from Analytic Number Theory.One of the important problems in this area that led to the development of the circle method is the Goldbach problem:

> *Statement:* Let $n\geq 4$ be even,then $n$ can be written as a sum of two primes.

Our instructor gave us a heuristic of how large the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of two primes can be.It is as follows:

Let $n$ be even,then the number of representations of $n$ as as sum of two primes should be about,

$\sum\limits_{n=n_1+n_2}\frac{1}{\log n_1}\frac{1}{\log n_2}\sim n/\log ^2n$

I think the expression on the LHS comes from some counting argument,but I am unable to figure out how the number comes.A little help will be helpful.

Comment: Speaking a little loosely, the probability that a randomly selected natural number $n$ is prime is about $\frac 1{\log n}$ (Prime Number Theorem).  This heuristic just assumes that if we write $n=n_1+n_2$ then the primality of the $n_i$ are independent events.

Comment: This estimation is poor quality. When $n$ is even, if $n_1+n_2=n$ and $n_1$ is odd, $n_2$ is odd also. So events are really not independant, and it seems we count twice $(a+b)$ and $(b+a)$.  BTW, an instructor to teach Goldbach, it is a very strange school.